# Could not convert string to float: 'x', Kmeans implemetation python

Tags: python, parsing, k-means

I try get a Silhouette index through kmeans implementation in python. I converter my cvs file to Tuple, but when I try get the k means clusters, get this error: **Could not convert string to float:x**.

This is my code:

```
def archCVS (filename): #Covert to CVS to Tuple
    fileHandelr = open(filename, "rt")
    lines= fileHandelr.readlines()
    fileHandelr.close()
    #del lines[0] #remove the header
    dataset=[]
    for line in lines:
        instance= lineToTuple(line)
        dataset.append(instance)
    return dataset

def lineToTuple(line): #Conver a comma separate string into tuple
    cleanLine=line.strip()
    cleanLine= cleanLine.replace('"', '')
    lineList=cleanLine.split(",")
    stringToNumbers(lineList)
    lineTuple=tuple(lineList)
    return lineTuple

def stringToNumbers(myList): #Convert string to numbers
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if(isValidNumberString(myList[i])):
            myList[i]=float(myList[i])

def isValidNumberString(s): #Number verification 
    if len(s)==0:
        return False
    if len(s) > 1 and s[0]=="-":
        s=s[1:]
    for  c in s:
        if c not in "0123456789.":
            return False
    return True

def KmeasandShilo(X):
    kmeans_model =KMeans(n_clusters=2,random_state=10).fit(X)
    labels=kmeans_model.labels_
    Silho= metrics.silhouette_score(X,labels,metric='euclidean')
    return Silho
```

I get this error

[Error imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2syCf.jpg)

What can I do?

Comment: Can you print out the value of X for which you are getting the error?

Comment: @BChow the result of x :  [(0.000264, 0.000352, 8.7e-05, 0.000549), (0.00016, 0.000223, 1.1e-05, 0.000142),
 (0.008853, 0.006519, 0.002043, 0.009819), (0.002076, 0.001686, 0.000959, 0.003107),
 (0.000599, 0.000133, 0.000113, 0.000466), (0.002264, 0.001927, 0.00079, 0.003815), 
 (0.002761, 0.00288, 0.001261, 0.006851), (0.000723, 0.000617, 0.000794, 0.002189),
 (0.000479, 0.000522, 0.000814, 0.001955), (0.002756, 0.000789, 6.7e-05, 0.000341), 
 (0.000884, 0.000478, 0.0, 0.000882), (0.000982, 0.000465, 0.000116, 0.000737)]

Comment: show the entire traceback message please, it would help a lot to see which part of your code raised the error.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen inside the post have a error imagem, thank for your help

Comment: take a look at the `local` variables in your IDE.  It sais that `X = 'x'` so I'd recommend trying to figure out why X is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

The list contains numbers in the scientific format (e-05) so maybe this is causing the problem. You will have to amend the function stringToNumbers. I recommend using

```
try:
  myList = map(float,myList)
except ValueError:
  print 'Error: in converting list = ',myList
```